# When using two google charts, one vertical axis disappears

Tags: javascript, html

When using two google charts, one vertical axis disappears.
The vertical axis of the first google chart works fine.
But the vertical axis of the second google chart is not visible.
Obviously I made two charts copy & paste,
I have two divs, what's wrong?

//This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript"> 
    /*<![CDATA[*/ 
    var year1 = /*[[ ${reallist3} ]]*/; //년별 매매
    var year2 = /*[[ ${reallist4} ]]*/; //년별 전월세
    /*]]>*/ 
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart(){
        var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data1.addColumn('string', 'Element');
        data1.addColumn('number', '가격');
        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data2.addColumn('string', 'Element');
        data2.addColumn('number', '가격');

        for(var i = 0; i < year1.length; i++){
                data1.addRow([year1[i].date + "(만원)", Number(year1[i].price)]);
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < year2.length; i++){
                data2.addRow([year2[i].date + "(만원)", Number(year2[i].price)]);
        }
         var view1 = new google.visualization.DataView(data1);
         view1.setColumns([0, 1,
            { calc: "stringify",
              sourceColumn: 1,
              type: "string",
              role: "annotation" }
         ]);

         var options1 = {
           width: 1100,
           height: 500,
           bar: {groupWidth: "50%"},
           legend: { position: "none" },
           vAxis: {minValue : 0},
           colors: ["pink","#81BEF7"],
           chartArea:{left:60,top:20,width:"80%",height:"85%"}
         };
         var chart1 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_real1"));
         chart1.draw(view1, options1);  

         var view2 = new google.visualization.DataView(data2);
         view2.setColumns([0, 1,
            { calc: "stringify",
              sourceColumn: 1,
              type: "string",
              role: "annotation" }
         ]);

         var options2 = {
            width: 1100,
            height: 500,
            bar: {groupWidth: "50%"},
            legend: { position: "none" },
            vAxis: {minValue : 0},
            colors: ["pink","#81BEF7"],
            chartArea:{left:60,top:20,width:"80%",height:"85%"}
          };
          var chart2 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("chart_real2"));
          chart2.draw(view2, options2); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a workable code. This code contains errors.

Comment: @tuhin47 
My code is working right now. Only the vertical axis of the second chart does not work.

Comment: please provide year1 and year2 data

Comment: year2 :
apart_name: "래미안부평"
area1: "84.963"
date: "201906"
floor: null
kinds: "전세"
price: "34000"

Comment: year1 : apart_name: "래미안부평"
area1: "59.923"
date: "201906"
floor: null
kinds: "매매"
price: "50128"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tuhin47/sfrp3d2h/ 
does your code generate the same output??

Comment: https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA3MTBfMjYz/MDAxNTYyNzMyNDUyNzY4.Jr4aUCvtGBXvYOH8q4DhObXuFaoJa1PNZFb9FRZnCB8g.AOK--n5J1MQNhGfCbGaR4MwwY3GxF5OXKQ3sqj4lJEwg.PNG.yhl8224/1.PNG?type=w773

Comment: Thank you tuhin47, 
I'm sorry for my problem...